Is $\Diamond \Box p$ "implies" $\Box \Diamond p$ a theorem in any modal logic?
I'm new to modal logic. Is it a known theorem in (one of the many) modal logic(s) that
$$\Diamond \Box p \quad \text{"implies"} \quad \Box \Diamond p\qquad?$$
More precisely, is either
$$\Diamond \Box p ~{}\rightarrow{}~ \Box \Diamond p \tag{$\dagger$}$$
a tautology or is the sequent
$$\Diamond \Box p ~{}\vdash{}~ \Box \Diamond p \tag{$\ddagger$}$$
derivable in a (known) modal logic system? If yes, in which axiom system and where can I find a proof?
Bonus question: If yes, is this also possible to prove when my modal logic has no negation operator whatsoever, nor an implication? (Obviously, then ($\dagger$) does not make any sense anymore.)

The formula $\Diamond \Box p \to \Box \Diamond p$ is the standard axiom for convergent Kripke frames. That is, whenever a world is related to two worlds, then those two worlds are both related to another world. This condition is met in system $\sf S5$ as well.
Since this formula is valid in convergent frames, it holds whenever you have both $\Diamond$ and $\Box$ available.

What's a convergent Kripke frame?

A tuple of a non-empty set of worlds and an accessibility relation between them such that for every world $w$, if $w$ is related to $v$ and also to $u$, then there is a world $x$ that both $v$ and $u$ are related to.

Thanks! What if I have no implication available?

The sequent is valid regardless in a convergent frame.
